# bash looping through file to find beginning of string

Tags: bash, awk

I have a large textfile with ~ 10,000 lines of data, whereby each line may have a different number of columns. For example:

```
789 KKPP 2018 08 09 10 20 30 AUTO A2987 10SM 5-MIN 22/13
790 KGOX 2018 08 09 10 20 35 AUTO P0002 21/19
...
798 KLXZ 2018 08 09 10 20 40 AUTO 18013GT 7SM 21/16 RMK A02 T02060156
799 KMNO 2018 08 09 10 20 45 AUTO 10SM P0001
...
...
```

I want to loop through every line and extract the 2nd column in which the prefix "P00*" appears. For example, in the above snippet of the file, I would want:

```
KGOX P0002
KMNO P0001
```

Which correspond to the lines 790 and 799. The number of columns are completely random, and can change from one row to the next. The most important thing is that somewhere in the row, some column of text starts with "P00".

I have a simple while read loop:

```
 while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "${line}" ]];
 do
 temp=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $7}')
 if [[ ${temp:0:3} == "P00" ]];
 then
 data=${temp}
 fi
 done
```

But this gets messy quickly, as the column numbers can exceed 30. Is there a simpler way to get this information and, perhaps, write to a text file? I know awk can do something that might work but can't get anything to work properly.

Comment: `as the columns range from 7~30`. So extract the columns from `7`th, with ____ `cut -d' ' -f7-`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In  you could use `awk`:

```
awk '{match($0,/.*(P000[^ ]+).*/,a)} a[1]{print $2,a[1] }' input
KGOX P0002
KMNO P0001
```

This will search for the pattern "`P00*` till next white space and store it into an array called "`a`".

Note: GNU awk is require for this to work.

Comment: If O.P. doesn't have GNU awk, then read the [Awk tutorial, match function](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#toc-uh-47) to get it working. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -En 's/^[^ ]+ ([^ ]+).*( P00[^ ]*).*/\1\2/p' file
```

Output:

```
KGOX P0002
KMNO P0001
```

Comment: perhaps add a space before the `P00` match to ensure it's the start of a word.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple `awk` script (standard Linux `gawk`)

```
awk 'match($0,/P000[^ ]+/,a){print $2, a[0]}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your input, maybe you could just go with:

```
grep 'P00.' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Comment: This misses the 2nd column

Answer (score 1):

Getting the 2nd column is the tricky part, since it's not always in the same place. There are some better answers with regexes (the match function is very handy), but a brute force approach is to print field two followed by every other field on the current line, then find the ones that match P00.

```
awk '{fld2=$2 ; split($0, a) ; for (f in a) { print fld2 " " a[f] } }' t | grep 'P00*'
KGOX P0002
KMNO P0001
```

Comment: `split($0, a) ; for (i in a) a[i]`is equivalent to `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i` for this case.